# Multiple initializer values for default property, 'viewport' of type 'spark.core.IViewport'

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Please, can anyone help me out on this : the piece of code below was working fine until i decided to add a scroller for better view and suddenly, i get the error:

```
"Multiple initializer values for default property, 'viewport' of type 'spark.core.IViewport'"
```

Thanks

```
[CODE]

  <s:Scroller
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    >

<s:Group id="basicDataGroup" includeIn="initial">

    <s:HGroup id="buttonGroup" 
              x="250" 
              paddingTop="20" 
              gap="15">
        <s:Button id="addBT" label="{resourceManager.getString('aggregationUI','add')}" click="addBT_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="delBT" label="{resourceManager.getString('aggregationUI','delete')}"/>
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:DropDownList id="languageCombo" 
                    prompt="{resourceManager.getString('aggregationUI','lang')}"
                    dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection([{locale:'fr_FI',label:'France'}, {locale:'en_US', label:'English'}])}"
                    change="languageChange(event)" 
                    width="100" 
                    x="473" 
                    y="20"/>

    <components:SearchComponent id="searchModel" searchClick="searchModel_searchClickHandler(event)"/>

    <components:DataComponent id="basicData" 
                              x="250" 
                              y="50"/>
</s:Group>

<s:Group id="newModelGroup" includeIn="newModel">
    <components:NewDataComponent id="newModelData"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
[/CODE]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A scroller can only be a viewport to one component.  In your scroller, you have basicDataGroup and newModelGroup.  Even though you have states so they don't both exist at the same time, I don't think Flex is that coordinated to know that.  Instead, wrap those two Groups in one Group, and make that parent Group the Scroller's viewport.

Hope that helps,
Ryan